# Nuget package not updating in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, package, package-managers

I'm creating a nuget package, which includes a few dlls. After the first iteration of this package, my team lead requested that I add another dll. I add it to the nuspec file, delete the old package from the server, and push the updated one. I go onto the server and verify that the newly added dll exists within the nuget package (i.e. I unzip the nuget package and inspect it's contents).

Everything looks good up to this point. Now, I go to install the newly created package into a test project, then clean and build. When I inspect the bin folder, it doesn't have the newly added dll. It's still the same dll set as the first package iteration, but on the nuget server it has all the updated dlls.

I've [cleared the nuget cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders), deleted the old package and re-applied changes, and restarted visual studio, all without success.

I believe the root cause is from the version number not being incremented with each iteration, due to requirements set by my team lead (which makes logical sense for the package itself). For example, when I update the Package-v1, the next update would still be Package-v1.

What can I do to force visual studio to grab the latest version from the server? Also, I'd like to know why this is happening if you know.

Comment: `the root cause is from the version number not being incremented with each iteration` Including a new DLL should dictate a version bump. You're not working with NuGet the way it was designed and wondering why it's not working.

Comment: @DanWilson I understand I'm not. All packages get incremented except this one, because the version number is dictated by one of the dll's it's consuming. Also, it's a requirement set by my team lead. I don't have the option to increment it.

Comment: NuGet packages are designed to be immutable. You can try to update them, but then you run into issues like the one you're facing. Your team lead is recommending an approach which violates this. The best you can do at this point is bump the version of the included DLL and use that to create a new package.

Comment: @DanWilson Unfortunately, I can't increment the version number of the dll, because it's managed by a third party vendor. However, I'll increment the package version (despite the dll version) and talk to my team lead about changing our approach.

Comment: I feel your pain. The package is obviously cached *somewhere*, I'm just not sure where.

Comment: @DanWilson When I incremented the package version manually, I got the desired results. As you said, it's cached **somewhere**, but I guess that would be part of the answer. Thanks for your help. I'm moving forward with the manual versioning for now and going to talk to my team lead about it. Thanks again.

Comment: Using NuGet's vocabulary, the cache is only an http cache to save things like what versions of a package exist on the server. The package is saved to the global packages folder, but nuget doesn't consider this a cache. You need to delete the package/version folder from the global packages folder to re-download the package from the package source

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What can I do to force visual studio to grab the latest version from the server? Also, I'd like to know why this is happening if you know.

The reason for this issue is that nuget always use the nuget cache or global-packages folders first to avoid downloading packages that already exist on the computer, improving the performance of install, update, and restore operations.

So, to resolve this issue, we should find out the nuget cache and delete it. It depends on the nuget package management type and `repositoryPath`/`globalPackagesFolder` settings in the `nuget.config` file.

If you nuget package management type is `packages.config`:

The **default** packages cache is in the `\packages` folder in the solution folder, you can check that package in the `\packages` folder. If not, check if you have any `nuget.config` with setting:

If yes, the packages cache will be saved on the new folder `YourCustomFolder`, delete that package from that folder.

If you nuget package management type is `packagereference`:

The **default** packages cache is in the global packages folder:

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\.nuget\packages
```

you can delete package in that folder, if you can not find the package from that global Packages Folder, check if you have any `nuget.config` with setting:

```
<add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="YourCustomFolder" />
```

If yes, delete package from the new folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Additionally, for people who this didn't work for: If the package is installed in a few projects, make sure you update it in all of them otherwise even if just one has the old version, for me the decompiler was showing the old version, no matter if I cleared the cache or I deleted the old version folder from the nuget cache. When I updated all of them, it finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

Run the command:

```
dotnet nuget locals all --clear
```

Helpfully, it'll tell you where the packages are being cleared from if you were wondering:

```
Clearing NuGet HTTP cache: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\NuGet\v3-cache
Clearing NuGet global packages folder: C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\
Clearing NuGet Temp cache: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch
Clearing NuGet plugins cache: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\NuGet\plugins-cache
Local resources cleared.
```